# Assignment to read-only properties is not allowed in strict mode in Edge Browser

Tags: file-upload, microsoft-edge

I want to copy the uploaded files the source input element to the destination input element. That is,I just assign the input.files from first element to the second element with the help of change event. I am getting wondered, it is not working in Edge browser.

It throws `Assignment to read-only properties is not allowed in strict mode`

Here's what I've tried.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-kobcul?file=index.ts

Hope I get some solution.

Comment: Looks like issue caused by Strict mode. Ref: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_strict.asp If possible then try to make a test with simple JS instead of using type script. Try to disable the strict mode if possible for you may help to avoid the issue.

Comment: I haven't used mode as strict. If I had did so,how to disable it?

Comment: You need to add add "noImplicitUseStrict": true to "compilerOptions" in tsconfig.json. Ref: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html and https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT , Is it possible to disable it dynamically? i,e., I'm declaring a function as strict but at some case, I don't want that function as strict and I want to change the function as non-strict.What I'm supposed to do.?

Comment: It is not possible to disable it dynamically. Because code needs to be complied again after you enable or disable it.

Comment: In some cases, drag and drop feature is not working in Edge browser. Is it a bug..??

Comment: The question you asked in your previous comment is not related with the question you posted in the original post. For a new question, it is recommended to create a new thread with detailed information about the issue with sample code or steps. If you got the answers for your question in the original post than I suggest you to mark the helpful suggestion as an answer. It can help other community members in future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently we don't have an option to assign the files to the input type file in edge browser. It seems to be a browser behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like issue caused by [Strict mode.](http://w3schools.com/js/js_strict.asp) If possible then try to make a test with simple JS instead of using type script. Try to disable the strict mode if possible for you may help to avoid the issue.

To disable the Strict mode, You need to add add "noImplicitUseStrict": true to "compilerOptions" in tsconfig.json.

[Compiler Options:](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html)

[tsconfig.json](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html)

It is not possible to disable it dynamically. Because code needs to be complied again after you enable or disable it.